# this.something outside each in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How would I use a `this.something` outside a each function

```
$(function(){

var json = '{ "list": [ { "something": "my string", "stuff": "this" }, { "something": "string of me", "stuff": that } ] }';

$.getJSON(json, function (data) {
    $.each(data.list, function() {
        $( "#someclassthatdoesntmatter" ).append("<div class='somediv'>"+something+"</div>")
        //here this.something is defined
        });
    });
//here I want to alert a 'something' on clicking the 'somediv' which it appended to
//didn't come further than: 
//$(document).on('click', '#somediv',function(){
//    alert(???);
//    });
});
```

How would I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which `this` do you want to alert? The last one? The first one? All of them?

Comment: Part of the problem is you're asking us `where` not `when`.

Comment: Impossible with asynchronous calls. That is why there are callbacks.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jQuery-getJSON-url-data-success-data--textStatus--jqXHR-

Comment: Ok updated, shouldn't be so bad that it'd get downvoted anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could do something like this:

On DOM Ready:

```
$('#someclassthatdoesntmatter').on('click', '.somediv', function() {
    alert($(this).data('something'));
});
```

Elsewhere:

```
$.getJSON(json, function (data) {
    $.each(data.list, function() {
        $("#someclassthatdoesntmatter").append('<div class="somediv" data-somthing="' + something + '">' + something + '</div>');        
    });
});
```

Ideally, you shouldn't append to the DOM in a loop, but this should give you an idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot -- this is 100% my solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON(json, function (data) {
    $.each(data.list, function() {
        UseObject(this);
        });
    });

});

function UseObject(obj)
{
    alert($(obj).something);
}
```

Comment: Problem is that each `obj` should be different for each div/click.